# Not all Python code executing in AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a simple lambda function which prints an event and then attempts to insert a row into a database. It runs with ****no** error**, but does not execute all of the code.

`event` gets printed, but the row never gets inserted into the table. Anything, even a print statement I put after `connection` doesn't get executed. I'm guessing something is wrong with the connection, but as far as I know I have no way of telling what is wrong. Are there more logs somewhere? In CloudWatch I see at the end it says Task timed out after 3.00 seconds

```
import boto3
import psycopg2

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def insert_data(event=None, context=None):
    print(event)

    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="xxxx", password="xxxx",
                                  host="xxxx", port="xx",
                                  database="xxxx")

    cursor = connection.cursor()
    postgres_insert_query = "INSERT INTO dronedata (name,lat,long,other) VALUES ('img2','54','43','from lambda')"
    cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query)
    connection.commit()
    count = cursor.rowcount
    print(count, "Record inserted successfully into mobile table")
```

Comment: Have you checked cloudwatch logs?

Comment: @Marcin Yes, I see that event gets printed and the last line it says Task timed out after 3.00 seconds. Does this just mean it is failing to reach the postgres database? Perhaps an connection/networking problem? I would have though I would have gotten an a different error.

Comment: If increasing the timeout does not help, then it is likely to be a problem communicating with the database. Check the configuration of the security groups on the database to ensure that inbound traffic is permitted. Is the database running on an instance, Amazon RDS or Amazon Redshift?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That was it! I'm using Amazon RDS. When I set it up, I allowed inbound only from my IP. It was working when I was testing on my computer, but not lambda, understandably. Thank you for the help. Can you submit as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical security setup is:

- A security group on the AWS Lambda function (`Lambda-SG`) that permits all outbound access (no need for inbound rules)
- A security group on the database (either an EC2 instance or Amazon RDS) (`DB-SG`) that permits inbound access on the appropriate port from `Lambda-SG`

That is, `DB-SG` should specifically reference `Lambda-SG` in its inbound rules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to increase default [Timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-console.html) from 3 seconds to more:

> Timeout – The amount of time that Lambda allows a function to run before stopping it. The **default is 3 seconds**. The maximum allowed value is 900 seconds.

[image]

Comment: I increased it to 30 seconds but still did not work. I don't think it should take that long to insert a row.

Comment: Secondary problem is connectivity to the DB. This will be either security groups (firewalls) or networking routing.

Comment: @fpolig01 John already gave answer for the second issue :-)

Answer (score 0):

hence `psycopg2` is an external lib, please upload that lib along with your code into your Lambda Function. So Issue is, it is not able to connect, that's why you are facing a timeout issue.

Comment: It had to do with my security configuration on the RDS instance. Lambda was unable to connect to it. I already packaged psycopg2 (had to build it on an AMI ec2 instance)

Comment: Did you check, you lambda execution role, that it has EC2 access or Not?

Comment: Otherwise, you can use Layer Feature in Lambda Function